# How to restore the DAG from its topologically sorted nodes?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I have a list of nodes that are the topological sort of some DAG. I want to restore the DAG - it's not necessary to be the original one - with the following properties:

- It may have multiple components.
- If there are intermediate nodes between A and B, then there can't be the direct edge between A and B.

Moreover, there is a function `f(Node1, Node2)` with a constant time-complexity that returns:

- `-1` if the Node2 can be reached from Node1.
- `0` if the Node1 and Node2 doesn't have a common root node.
- `1` if the Node1 can be reached from Node2.

So, if `f()` return non-zero value, then the nodes should be somehow connected.

---

The answer, proposing the algorithm with the least time-complexity, will be accepted.

---

**P.S.** It's possible that I will update the DAG properties to exclude some trivial cases.

Comment: What did you try? Where did it fail? Wasn't fast enough?

Comment: Hi. This doesn't seem to be [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow because it doesn't relate to a *specific instance of* a programming problem. Perhaps you should try asking this on one of the [other](http://stackexchange.com/sites#technology) Stack Exchange [sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites#science) instead?

Comment: @GoBusto I disagree, it is perfectly on-topic as an algorithimic question (search the algorithm tag, there are lot's of them) - but I am concerned however from the lack of research shown by OP

Comment: @amit I want to add my research as an answer, when I'm done. I'm doing it right now. Is it fair enough, or should I add my research to the question?

Comment: @abyss.7 Answering your own question is fine - but you should still provide some insight of research. The naive O(n^2) solution would do